# How to solve 'WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type' error with Selenium and Eclipse?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using latest Eclipse (2023-03) with latest JavaSE-17, followed all the steps to add Jar files for selenium webdriver

1. right-click on project--> goto build path--> configure build path
2. Click on Classpath node which is just below the Modulepath node.
3. click "Add external jars"--> add selenium jar files **(Latest version 4.9.1)** from your local machine-->
4. Click Apply and Close button.
   but still getting error "WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wR7w.png)

Followed all the steps

1. right-click on project--> goto build path--> configure build path
2. Click on Classpath node which is just below the Modulepath node.
3. click "Add external jars"--> add selenium jar files from your local machine-->
4. Click Apply and Close button.
   but still getting error "WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 0):

Import the `WebDriver` interface and `Firefox` class. See the code below:

```
package Test1.Test1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

**Note:** Its `FirefoxDriver()` and not `firefoxDriver()`